# What do braces do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I read this line in *Eloquent JavaScript* and would love some clarity.

> ...braces have two meanings in JavaScript. At the start of a statement, they start a block fo statements. In any other position, they describe an object. Fortunately, it is almost never useful to start a statement with a brace object, and...

So, braces in let's say a..... an 'if statement' create a block of statements to execute, but braces that appear in let's say a function call (as a parameter) or in a variable assignment becomes an object literal.

Is that right? What are all the other cases? I'm not sure I understand the rule for when braces bundle up statements and for when they describe an object.

Comment: When they are used in a statement context - they are a statement, an object literal or a destructuring literal otherwise.

Comment: What is 'statement context'? Isn't everything in a program made up of statements and expressions?

Comment: `var a = {};` <--- here is an assignment statement that consists of a keyword,a variable name, an assignment operator and a value (an object).

Comment: Strictly, braces are [*punctuators*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-punctuators) that have a different meaning depending on where they are in the code. They are used to denote blocks and object literals, but only where such structures are allowed. An object literal (a "brace object") can never be the start of a statement.

Comment: I think I understand. So if after an equal sign (assignment operator) or in the position of a function parameter in a function call,.... or in an array, or after a colon in an object, wow lots of places, then it's an object literal, but otherwise it denotes a block of statements?

Comment: Or not 'otherwise' because they can't be at the beginning of a statement. Seems complex.

Comment: Oh, ECMAScript 2015 has introduced the term [*BlockStatement*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-block), which is a block and the (optional) enclosed statements. Hard to see how that is better than the previous plain [*Block*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.1).

Comment: I think it might have to do with scope, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Costa: "*Isn't everything in a program made up of statements and expressions?*" - Exactly. And `{}` as an expression means something different than `{}` as a statement.

Comment: @Bergi So, how can I tell when `{}` is being an expression vs a statement?

Comment: @Costa it is an expression when it produces a result or is a part of another expression.

Comment: Haa, yeah I know that, I use them all the time. How does JavaScript know? Is there a rule of thumb, or just a list of possible uses?

Comment: @Costa: There's [a grammar](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-statements) and the parser decides it. An expression statement is not allowed to start with a `{`, so it's rather simple. So neither just a rule of thumb, nor just a list of examples, but a definitive grammar rule that is carefully crafted to be deterministic.

Comment: Note that the quoted section does not include [*Destructuring Assignment*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-destructuring-assignment).

Comment: Okay, I think I'm getting it. I certainly know it from how I use JavaScript. It's interesting going back and reading a book on the language after having used it for so long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### as object literals

```
var a = {field1:value1, field2:value2}
```

#### as function bodies

```
function func() {
    // do something
}
var f = function() { /* do something */ };
var f = ()=>{}; // ditto
```

#### where the first item in the statement is an object literal

```
// {}.toString(); // syntax error, first brace of statement = code block
({}).toString(); // correct
```

#### as destructured assignment

```
var obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
var {a:x, c:y} = obj; // assign obj.a to x, and obj.c to y
({a:x, c:y} = obj); // ditto
```

Note - this has a *lot* of forms so I won't cover them all, [full info found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) (thanks RobG)

### how this is interpreted

You can assume that all your JS code is inside some `{}` block. So the start of your code is immediately after a `{` always.

Wherever a *value* is expected, `{}` does not mean a function body. At the start of a statement this is ambiguous because you can have anonymous code blocks like so:

```
var x = 1;
{
    var x = x+2;
    // x = 3
}
// x = 3 (!)
```

This is archaic from C-style syntax where this would influence scope, but in testing this in JS it doesn't seem to have that effect, so for all intents it's rather useless syntax except to identify a code block. If you wanted such behavior you'd need to do this:

```
var x = 1;
(()=>{
    var x = x+2;
    // x = 3
})()
// x = 1
```

If we need an object first in some statement, we need to clarify to JS that we want a *value*. This is why we use `({})` instead of `{}`, because the former is unambiguously an object literal inside parens.

---

#### a simpler explanation

Rather than examine when `{}` is parsed as a value, let's look at when it isn't. There are two cases in general where we *don't* treat `{}` as an object literal: as a function body or as a *statement group* (my own term).

Consider the general control statements - `if`, `for`, `while`, `with` etc. These can all* be used in a way that *completely* avoids `{}`. In this respect `{}` should be thought of as *statement groups* hence the term.

```
if (x) x++; else x--;
if (x) {x++;} else {x--;}
{if (x) {x++;} else {x--;}}
```

*note: `switch` is an exception, `switch(1);` gives an error `SyntaxError: missing { before switch body`

Using this rule it then makes sense why we *must* use `()` to denote an object literal if it's the start of a statement - we can't *start* a statement in `()`, so you can't start a statement group there either, leaving only one option (object literal or related syntax).

This leaves function bodies.

#### function bodies

First, consider a function declaration statement:

```
function f () {}
```

It doesn't need a semicolon (`;`). This means the entire thing is a single statement. This explains why the following gives a syntax error in the first form but not the second:

```
function(){return 1;}(); // error: function statement requires name
var x = function(){return 1;}(); // fine
```

This is because the first is parsed as a statement, and a function declaration statement cannot be anonymous. However the second is in a *value context* and is treated as such. The situation is *identical* as with object literals, if it could be a statement it cannot be a value, but if we're already knee deep in value land, it *has to be* a value.

The `=>` notation is, with one exception, parsed identically to `function`. The `()=>{}` form is identical but in practice differs because this type of function cannot have a `this` object - it cannot be an object method (doesn't make much sense to) and it cannot construct new objects (it has no prototype), and other quirks as a result. otherwise it's straightforward to see how it's the same as `function(){}`.

`()=>...` however is a little different. It's treated as `()=>{return ...}`. But, without the explicit `}` to finish the return statement, the syntax greedily captures the largest expression that would *parse* as such (not necessarily *work*). Case in point:

```
()=>1; // statement; = function that returns "1"
()=>1(); // statement; = function that returns "1()"
(()=>1()); // TypeError: 1 is not a function
(()=>1)(); // what was intended in above (you'd hope)
```

Comment: There are many many other use cases. How does JavaScript know whether to create a new object, or a block of statements?

Comment: You are missing [*Destructuring Assignment*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-destructuring-assignment), also see [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: @RobG thanks i'll update my answer with that shortly. it's similar to pattern match syntax (eg ERLANG) oddly enough...

Comment: @Costa in a sentence: if at some point in code you are unsure if it's a block or an object, it's a block. an object _must_ be in a context where it's being assigned to or itself used as a value, and where this is unclear it's presumed a block first. Eg `()=>({})` is a function that returns an object while `()=>{}` is a function that does nothing.

Comment: @XerenNarcy, the cases where it's a value are quite numerous. After `=` after `:` sometimes, after `case` (after case?) after `[` or `,` in an array. There's lots of places where a value is expected.

Comment: @Costa yep, and in all of those places would you confuse braces for a block or would you unambiguously expect object-literal syntax?

Comment: @XerenNarcy I'd expect an object literal, but only because I'm familiar with the situations, not because I understand the rule. I'm just hungering for simplicity, it's okay if there isn't any.

Comment: @Costa ok, fair enough. the simplest is: if it could be a block, it is, otherwise it's an object. again, keeping it absolutely simple, we can check JS parsing rules for when a block is expected (or could be present). if we ignore function blocks (`function` and `=>` symbols) it's _anywhere a statement can start_. eg, immediately after control statements (`if`,`for`,`while` etc), and even without one (ie, `if(x)x++` and `{if(x){x++}}`, both are grouping multiple or compound statements as one). for this reason starting with `(` works: you can't start a statement inside `()` only an expression.

Comment: That's super thorough! Thanks so much : )