# Increment Javascript object member dynamically

Tags: javascript, object

Essentially, I desire the function to read all letters from a string, and to spit out an object that contains `{'letter', 'count'}` properties for each letter.

```
function freqLetters(string) {
  var freq = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    var character = string.charAt(i);
    if (typeof freq[character] != undefined) {
      freq[character].count++;
    } else {
      freq.push({'letter': character, 'count': 1});
    }
  }

  return freq;
}
```

However, freq usually appears empty and when it works, it seems to always fail the `'!=== undefined'` check and push duplicate letters of 1 count, rather than finding them and increment them.

Is the `typeof freq[character] !=== undefined]` check correct?

How on earth do I increment dynamic elements?

(i.e. find letter:a if it exists, and increment its count by 1 if it exists)

Comment: Try setting the if as `if(typeof freq[character] != "undefined")...`.

Comment: It says there is an undefined member of 'count' now.. I try `freq[character].count++;` and all sorts of while testing, and it seems to just append to the array as if it's a new letter each time(so likely the `!= undefined` still fails) (oops I fixed the ] typo)

Comment: Ah!! I'm now noticing that you are using the character as index... I wouldn't do that....

Comment: As for the `if`, the `!= "undefined"` part is correct. The problem is with the left part.

Answer (score 2):

Functional programming woo.

```
var counts = string
    .split('') // Get individual letters.
    .reduce((acc, letter)=> {
        // acc is an object (passed in as second arg to reduce).
        // we use the existing value for the letter (default to 0) and add one each time.
        acc[letter] = (acc[letter] || 0) + 1
        return acc
    }, {})
```

---

Edit: Realized you wanted an array or { letter: count } objects.

```
var countsList = Object
    .keys(counts)
    .map((key)=> ({ [key]: counts[key] }))
```

Comment: can make it smaller still changing `(key)=> { return { [key]: counts[key] } }` to `(key)=>({ [key]: counts[key] })`

Comment: Dude. I never thought about wrapping the returned objects in parans to avoid using returns. Your the bomb.

Comment: Nor did I, heh, but [it came up recently](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38388011/5134012) so thought I'd share

Comment: I've used it for 'object switches' like `x = ({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 })['c']` which is cool but not this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check existence of letter, don't use an array object. Because push function add element indexed by number (0, 1, 2) so freq[character] is always undefined.

For your instanciation :

```
var freq = {};
```

in your else :

```
freq[character] = {'letter': character, 'count': 1}
```

And in your if, check just the existence :

```
if (freq[character]) {... }
```

Comment: Also if you're super paranoid about the presence of keys, you can use `if (character in freq) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below code:

```
function countCharacters(exampleString){
var countObject = {} ; 
for (var i = 0, l = exampleString.length; i < l; i++) {
    var currentChar =  exampleString.charAt(i);
    if(typeof(currentChar) != undefined) {
        countObject[currentChar] = characterCount(exampleString, currentChar);
    }
}
console.log(countObject);
return(countObject); }



function characterCount(word, character) {
   var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
       if (word[i] === character) {
           count++;
       }
  }
  return count; }
```

Hope it helps :)